# Import CV2: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found while successful pip installation

Tags: python, windows, opencv

I was working with Python 3.7 and OpenCV 4.2 in Pycharm IDE (Windows10). The system environment variables were changed by one of my co-workers by accident (we don't know what happened exactly). Then I found that my code did not work with this error!:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

Then I used this command:

```
pip uninstall opencv-python
pip uninstall opencv-contrib-python
pip install opencv-python
```

All of them executed successfully, but when I write `import cv2` the above error is appeared. By the way, the system knows command `Python`, it shows the right path to the `python.exe`. Moreover, commands like `import numpy` works correctly! How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer! There was an extra `cv2.py` file in `site-packages/cv2` path. So, I removed it and the code worked